# Effective types of allocated objects and structs

Tags: c, struct, malloc, language-lawyer, c99

From c99's spec I cannot quite understand what is going on with the effective type of the below allocated object.

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    char y;
} MyStruct ;

MyStruct *make_struct (void) {
    MyStruct *p = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
    p->x = 1;
    p->y = 2;

    /* what is the effective type of the allocated object at this point? */

    return p;
}
```

When you assign a value to an allocated object, the effective type of the allocated object becomes the type of the lvalue used for the store, but what is the lvalue used here?

As far as I understand from 6.5.2.3p4...

> A postfix expression followed by the -> operator and an identifier designates a member of a structure or union object. The value is that of the named member of the object to which the first expression points, and is an lvalue. If the first expression is a pointer to a qualified type, the result has the so-qualified version of the type of the designated member.

...the type of an "x->y" expression is the type of y (but only if x points to a qualified type).
So then I have an allocated object with no effective type and two "inner objects" with types int and char?

How confusing..

Edit:
Suppose the effective type of *p ends up as int. Is this undefined behavior then? Someone will end up accessing the object via an lvalue with type MyStruct. Does accessing a member imply accessing the aggregate type too?
This keeps on giving..

Comment: `p` is still a pointer to MyStruct type, `x` is int and `y` is char, if this is what you're asking.

Comment: Well, `*p` has a declared type.

Comment: No, it doesn't; *p is an allocated object and has no declared type.

Comment: `malloc()` returns `void *`. This is a special type that can be allocated to any other pointer without an explicit cast and without causing a compiler warning.

Comment: @James: The C standard has particular rules about the *effective type* of an object that go beyond merely what type of pointer is used to access them. The fact that `malloc` returns a `void *` is not informative in this regard.

Comment: Can anybody provide a link to the spec that has 6.5.2.3p4?

Comment: @James "*4 A postfix expression followed by the -> operator and an identifier designates a member of a structure or union object. The value is that of the named member of the object to which the first expression points, and is an lvalue. If the first expression is a pointer to a qualified type, the result has the so-qualified version of the type of the designated member.*"

Comment: _Suppose the effective type of `*p` ends up as int. Is this undefined behavior then? Someone will end up accessing the object via an lvalue with type MyStruct_ http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7 seem to allow accessing an object through an lvalue of struct/union type having member with effective type of the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotes are from C99 6.5/6

> > The *effective type* of an object for an access to its stored value is the declared type of the object,  if any.

- `malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));` At this point, the returned data has no effective type.
- `MyStruct *p = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));` Still no effective type, `p` just points at the data without storing anything.
- `p->x = 1;` The effective type rule:

  > If a value is stored into an object having no declared type through an
  >   lvalue having a type that is not a character type, then the type of the lvalue becomes the effective type of the object for that access and for subsequent accesses that do not modify the stored value.

  Since we have `int x;` the lvalue of the expression `p->x = 1;` is `int` and it becomes the effective type of what's stored at `p->x`.
- In case of `p->y` the lvalue used for object access is a character type, so the above rule doesn't apply. Nor is it copied as a character array. We end up in the final sentence of the rule:

  > For all other accesses to an object having no declared type, the effective type of the object is simply the type of the lvalue used for the access.

  Meaning the effective type of `p->y` becomes `char`, since the lvalue of the expression `p->y = 2;` is `char`.

6.5.2.3/4 has no relevance here, apart from "...and is an lvalue".

`*p` has no effective type as such, because we never accessed the memory area through a complete struct type. However, an expression such as `MyStruct m = *make_struct();` is still well-defined, since the strict aliasing rule allows a struct access to the objects, given that the struct contains members that are compatible with the effective types. In this case, the struct contains `int` and `char` members that are perfectly compatible with the effective types that the data referred through with `p->x` and `p->y` ended up with.

Comment: I think it's clear that "through an lvalue" refers to the expression "p->x", not 1 which represents the value (a.k.a rvalue) being stored.

Comment: @zagortenay333 I might have misread that part indeed. This part of the standard is quite horribly written. I'll edit. The resulting type is the same either way.

Comment: Think I got the language lawyering right this time. Proof-reading appreciated :)

Comment: I don't see how the effective type could end up as char. If the type of "p->x" is an int, then the effective type remains int for all operations that don't modify (since "p->y" can't change anything here.) But I don't understand what the type of "p->x" even is; it's completely non-obvious to me.

Comment: Also, if the final effective type is int, then the above code invokes undefined behaviour, since someone will access an object with effective type int using an lvalue that will be MyStruct. I mean, can you even access a struct or only it's members?

Comment: @zagortenay333 As far as the compiler knows, there is no struct at that memory location. There is an `int` in one location and a `char` in another, since that's how you accessed them. The part you quoted regarding the -> operator makes this clear. The first expression`p` "points" (read: refers) to a struct type where the named member is x. This isn't really written with the concept of effective type in mind, since effective type was added in C99 but the text in 6.5.2.3 remains since C90.

Comment: @zagortenay333 Regarding strict aliasing, the function only returns a pointer, the contents are never de-referenced through a pointer type, so it doesn't apply. But even when it does, the strict aliasing rule has an exception for structs: "an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its
members". A struct being an aggregate type that includes the aforementioned "type compatible with the effective type of the object". In plain English: accessing the `int` object through a pointer to a struct containing a `int` member is fine and exempt from the rule.

Comment: @zagortenay333 Regarding your edit, I think I finally understand the source of your confusion. The whole of the data pointed by `p` has no effective type through any of this. `p->x` has the effective type `int` and `p->y` has effective type `char`, respectively. In order to make the whole data effective type struct, you would have to write something like `*p = (MyStruct){1,2};` which is not the case here. `p` could as well have been a `void*` and you could have written something horrid like `*(int*)p = 1` and `((char*)p)[sizeof(int)] = 2;` and it would have had the same effect.

Comment: "The whole of the data" yes that's what I was refering to! My assumption was that malloc returns a single object. The fact that this access pattern renders it as two separate objects is kind of weird to me. Looking at the definition of object as "region of data storage" I guess it makes sense. I think your two comments here should probably be the answer here.

Comment: @zagortenay333 For the purpose of effective type, you have to think of malloc as returning a chunk of unidentified bytes, as many as you asked for. The type of the pointer has no relevance at all.

Comment: @Lundin, I can't seem to figure out the difference between *"If a value is stored into an object having no declared type through an lvalue having a type that is not a character type, then the type of the lvalue becomes the effective type of the object ..."*, as opposed to "*For all other accesses to an object having no declared type, the effective type of the object is simply the type of the lvalue used for the access.*". The first one excludes char types, but apart from that I think they both say the exact same thing - the effective type of the object being assigned is that of the [...]

Comment: [...] lvalue the value is being set through. What's the difference?

Comment: The first case specifically mentions a write (store), after which the effective type of that area changes from no effective type, to the type used when writing to that area. The second case is for accessing, including reads. Take for example `int* foo = malloc(sizeof *foo);`. The area that foo points at has no effective type. Then we do `int x = *foo;`, this is a lvalue read access and the effective type for this specific access is `int`. `foo` still points at an object with no effective type. ->

Comment: But if we do `*foo = 1;` writing an `int`, the effective type of what `foo` points at changes from no effective type to `int` from here on. Meaning that a subsequent access of `double* bar = (double*)foo); double d = *bar;` is a strict aliasing violation. Or at least this is how it all should work in _theory_. What compilers do in practice is another story, sadly. Because this part of the standard is ambiguous and poorly written.

Comment: @Lundin So - is it correct to say that a piece of memory can only have its effective type set, once? I.e. - once we did `*foo = 1` and set the memory pointed to by `foo` to effective type `int`, we can never do `*((double*) foo) = 2.5` in order to set the effective type to `float`.

Comment: @AvivCohn Yes pretty much, but an area can have more than one effective type if you use union etc.

Comment: @Lundin, Hmm, that's interesting. I had a discussion on this topic in the comments to this answer to a question of mine (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61297634/3284878). In it, the person confirmed my more recent understanding of the text, that it's impossible to violate SAR by performing a write-dereference. And that it's only possible to violate SAR by performing a read-dereference.  I.e. - if memory area A had effective type X, and later we reassign its effective type to Y, it is now legal to read-dereference memory area A through lvalue of type Y. Don't you agree?

Comment: @AvivCohn: The Effective Type abstraction has some tricky and unworkable corner cases that cannot be handled correctly without impeding optimization in some more common cases.  The only way the rule would make any sense would be if the authors assumed that it would be impossible for a compiler to behave meaningfully in all cases where the Standard required it without also behaving meaningfully in some other cases, and there was thus no need to explicitly accommodate all cases that should be useful.  Their assumption might have been correct, since neither clang nor gcc handles all the tricky...

Comment: ...corner cases correctly.  As such, I don't think there's much value in trying to interpret whether the Standard would require that implementations accommodate various corner cases.  Most implementations can be configured to reliably process some corner cases the Standard clearly doesn't require, and those that aren't configured to do so shouldn't be trusted to handle all of the corner cases the Standard does require.  The fact that the Standard does or doesn't require an implementation to handle a construct usefully doesn't imply that any particular implementation will do so.

Comment: @AvivCohn To sum up what's said in C17 6.5./6, there are two different cases: objects that have a _declared type_, such as `int x;`, and objects that have _no declared type_, such as chunks returned from malloc, pointers to addresses where the compiler can't know what's stored etc. The former can never change their effective type, but objects with no declared type can have the effective type changed by a write access.

Comment: @AvivCohn Also please don't invent new three letter abbreviations, it's a disease. "SAR" in the context of computer engineering already means Successive Approximation Register and refers to a certain category of Analog-To-Digital converters (SAR ADC).

Answer (score 3):

The allocated block does not have an effective type, because (1) it has no declared type, and (2) it has not been assigned. Parts of the block that correspond to members `x` and `y` have effective types, but not the entire block.

Not having an effective type does not constitute undefined behavior, though: each member of `MyStruct` returned from `make_struct` has been given a proper effective type individually, so the code accessing members of the returned `struct` remains valid.

Your code fragment could be modified to use a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) to initialize the whole of `MyStruct`, rather than initializing its components. This would make the effective type of the allocated block `MyStruct`:

```
MyStruct *make_struct () {
    MyStruct *p = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));
    *p = (MyStruct){.x = 1, .y = 2};
    return p;
}
```

**Note:** This answer has been significantly edited after an update to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The term "object" as used everywhere in the C11 draft (N1570) except 6.5p6 (the "Effective Type Rule") refers to a region of storage which is associated with some particular type.  If `int *p` is a valid non-null pointer, it will point "to", or "just past", an object of type `int`.  It seems like 6.5p6 uses the term "object" to refer to some kind of region of storage that may or may not actually be an object, but the rest of the Standard does not use the term "object" in such a fashion.  Among other things, the specification for `malloc` does *not* say that it returns a pointer to an object, nor that it creates an object, but rather that it returns a pointer to a region of storage large enough to hold an object of the given size.

Because 6.5p6 uses the term "object" in a way which is contrary to its usage everywhere else, its meaning will depend upon how one chooses to define the term.  In the absence of footnote 87 ("Allocated objects have no declared type.") one could resolve this issue by simply observing that the effective type of every object is simply its type.  This would actually work just fine if one recognized regions of storage as holding a superposition of all objects that could fit therein, but interpreted footnote 88 of 6.5p7 ("The intent of this list is to specify those circumstances in which an object may or may not be aliased.") as saying that the only "objects" to which the rule applies are those which are used in the same context as an lvalue without having been freshly and visibly used in that lvalue's derivation.

As it is, however, footnote 87 makes clear that 6.5p6 must use a different meaning of "object" from everything else in the Standard, without making clear what that meaning is.  I don't think it's possible to formulate a definition that handles all corner cases reasonably, and it seems doubtful that the authors of the Standard had a consensus meaning for what things were or were not "objects" for purposes of 6.5p6 or 6.5p7.  Consequently, the meaning of 6.5p6 and 6.5p7, and what will be allowable based upon them, will be largely dependent upon how a reader chooses to bodge the meaning of "object".