# Effective type rules with relation to strict aliasing

Tags: c, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

So, I've been banging my head against the Strict Aliasing Rule and the effective type rules for the past couple of days. While the spirit of it is pretty clear, I'd like to nail down a good technical understanding of the rules. Please note I've gone through many related questions on SO, but I don't feel that the questions to be presented here have been answered in a way that really sits with me in any other place.

This question is divided into two parts.

In the first part, I divide the effective type rules into sentences, and explain my own understanding of each one. For each of these, please validate my understanding if it is correct, or correct me if it's flawed and explain why it is. For the last "sentence", I also present two questions that I would appreciate answers to.

The second part of the question concerns my understanding of the SAR.

**Part 1: Effective type rules**

**Sentence 1**

> The effective type of an object for an access to its stored value is the declared type of the object, if any.

This is pretty clear - a declared object such as `int x` has a permanent effective type, which is the type it is declared with (`int` in this case).

**Sentence 2**

> If a value is stored into an object having no declared type through an lvalue having a type that is not a character type, then the type of the lvalue becomes the effective type of the object for that access and for subsequent accesses that do not modify the stored value.

An "object having no declared type" is generally a dynamically allocated object.

When we store data inside an allocated object (*whether or not it already has an effective type*) the effective type of the object becomes the type of the lvalue used to access the data for storing (unless the lvalue is of character type). So for example:

```
int* x = malloc(sizeof(int)); // *x has no effective type yet
*x = 10; // *x has effective type int, because the type of lvalue *x is int
```

It is also possible to change the effective type of an object that already has an effective type. For example:

```
float* f = (float*) x;
*f = 20.5; // *x now has effective type float, because the type of lvalue *f is float.
```

**Sentence 3**

> If a value is copied into an object having no declared type using memcpy or memmove, or is copied as an array of character type, then the effective type of the modified object for that access and for subsequent accesses that do not modify the value is the effective type of the object from which the value is copied, if it has one.

This means that when we set a value into an allocated object, if the value is set through an lvalue of type compatible with `char*` (or through `memcpy` and `memmove`), the effective type of the object becomes the effective type of the data that is copied into it. For example:

```
int* int_array = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5); // *int_array has no effective type yet
int other_int_array[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
char* other_as_char_array = (char*) other_int_array;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(int) * 5; i++) {
    *((char*) int_array + i) = other_as_char_array[i];
}
// *int_array now has effective type int
```

**Sentence 4**

> For all other accesses to an object having no declared type, the effective type of the object is simply the type of the lvalue used for the access.

I have two question regarding this part:

A. By "*For all other accesses*", does the text simply mean "for all *read* accesses"?

It seems to me that all the previous rules that refer to objects of undeclared types, only deal with *storing* a value. So is this simply the rule for any *read* operation against an object of undeclared type (which may or may not already have an effective type)?

B. A particular object in memory only ever has one effective type. So - what does the text mean by "For all other *accesses*"... It's not a matter of the access, it's a matter of the objective effective type of the object. Isn't it? Please clarify the language of the text.

**Part 2: A question about Strict Aliasing**

The strict aliasing rule description starts like so (emphasis mine):

> An object shall have its **stored value accessed** only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types [...]

When the text says "stored value accessed" - does it mean both read and write accessing, or only read?

As another way to ask this question: does the following code constitute a Strict Aliasing violation or is it legal?

```
int* x = malloc(sizeof(int)); // *x - no effective type yet
*x = 8; // *x - effective type int
printf("%d \n", *x); // access the int object through lvalue *x

float* f = (float*) x; // casting itself is legal
*f = 12.5; // effective type of *x changes to float - *** is this a SAR violation? ***
printf("%g \n", *f); // access the float object through lvalue *f
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"access" means read or write. "For all other accesses" means any accesses not already covered in that paragraph. To recap, the accesses to objects of no declared type that have been covered are:

- a value is stored into an object having no declared type through an
  lvalue having a type that is not a character type,
- subsequent accesses that do not modify the stored value
- a value is copied into an object having no declared type using
  memcpy or memmove
- or is copied as an array of character type

So the remaining case of "all read and writes" are:

- a value is stored into an object having no declared type through an lvalue having a type that **is** a character type,
- any other writes we didn't think of

In part 2 the code is correct according to the text of C11 as per:

> If a value is stored into an object having no declared type through an
>   lvalue having a type that is not a character type, then the type of the lvalue becomes the
>   effective type of the object for that access

`*x = 8;` stores a value into an object having no declared type through an lvalue having a type that is not a character type. So the effective type of the object for this access is `int`,  and then in 6.5/7 we have the object of effective type `int` being accesses by an lvalue of type `int`.  The same reasoning applies to `*f = 20.5` with `float` instead of `int`.

*Footnote:* there are many reasons to believe the text of 6.5/6 and /7 to be defective, as you will have seen from searching other questions on the topic. People (and compiler writers) form their own interpretation of the rule .

Comment: I see. Let me validate my understanding: I think we agree that SAR deals with restrictions on the act of accessing a stored value through a particular lvalue ("*An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types: ...*"). And, my understanding of your writing in practice, is that it is always legal, in of it's own, to *set* a stored value through any lvalue we want. Such an access would always set the effective type of the object either to the type of the lvalue, or to the type of the data being copied, whether or not it [...]

Comment: [...] already has an effective type. This will be the effective type for all subsequent accesses that do not modify the value (i.e., read accesses). So if I understand correctly, *any store access*, i.e. assignment, copy, etc. would happen to set the effective type of the underlying object to one that happens to match the lvalue being currently used, as far as SAR is concerned.  If so - do you agree that SAR is only relevant to accesses that *read* a particular object? I.e. - it is impossible to violate SAR by making a particular assignment or copy. It's only possible to violate SAR by [...]

Comment: [...] dereferencing for *reading* something, through an lvalue incompatible with the underlying effective type. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @AvivCohn For objects with no declared type, yes

Comment: The SO tag on Strict Aliasing quotes an article by Mike Acton, the defines Strict Aliasing like so: "*Strict aliasing is an assumption, made by the C (or C++) compiler, that dereferencing pointers to objects of different types will never refer to the same memory location (i.e. alias each other).*". My understanding right now is that according to SAR, it may definitely be okay for two pointers of different types to alias each other, even in the same area of the code, like shown above. It's only a problem, correct me if I'm wrong, [...]

Comment: [...] if a read-dereference of pointer B comes after a write-dereference of pointer A, without a preceding write-dereference of pointer B (i.e. the pointer accesses are "intertwining"). If so (?), than is it safe under any conforming compiler such as GCC to write code like the above? Or do we risk the compiler optimizing stuff in weird ways and breaking the code? Because the above code does seem in the spirit of what some places online consider something the compiler might break.

Comment: @AvivCohn yes, for objects of no declared type according to the standard. (But see DR 236 that suggests the standard is defective but with no resolution in mind)

Comment: @AvivCohn: If you look at Defect Report #028, there seems to be a presumption that reads and writes of different-type pointers to the same object would have the same semantics as reads and writes of union members, and because writing one member and reading another invokes Implementation-Defined Behavior, writing a one pointer of one type and reading another invokes Undefined Behavior.  The Effective Type rules codify that non-sequitur.

Comment: @supercat "*...writing one member and reading another invokes Implementation-Defined Behavior...*" - isn't that true for C++ but not for C? Pretty sure C allows unions for type punning. And excuse my non-native English, but what do you mean by "The Effective Type rules codify that non-sequitur" (looked up "non-squitur" but not sure what you meant by this in this context).

Comment: @AvivCohn: In C89, the behavior was characterized as "implementation-defined"; I think that was probably intended as a shorthand way of saying its behavior would generally depend upon the implementation-defined representations of the types involved, but in any case the behavior was supposed to be consistent in any situation where code read an object with a valid bit pattern.  DR #028 said that because the behavior with unions is Implementation-Defined, the behavior with pointers is Undefined.  No reason was given for the latter not having the same Implementation Defined Behavior as the former.

Comment: @AvivCohn: If the DR had said that there is no *general* permission to use lvalues of struct or union member type to access struct or union members, but quality compilers should make a reasonable effort to recognize and accommodate situations where code uses an lvalue of--or pointer to--an object of type X to form a pointer of type `Y*` another and then accesses it via the resulting pointer, that would have resolved DR #028 easily, since nothing within the example function would suggest a need for such accommodation.

Comment: Does the Standard ever say when an operation constitutes "copying as an array of character type", or what one would need to do if one needed to make all of the bytes of one object hold the same values as those of another while still allowing the object to be accessed as its original type?

Answer (score 0):

So far as I can tell, there has never been any consensus understanding among committee members as to what the "Effective Type" rules are supposed to mean in all corner cases; any plausible interpretation will either forbid what should be useful optimizations, fail to accommodate what should be usable constructs, or both.  So far as I can tell, no compiler that is nearly as "strict" as clang and gcc correctly handles all of the corner cases posed by the rules in a manner consistent with any reasonable interpretation of the Standard.

```
struct s1 { char x[1]; };
struct s2 { char x[1]; };

void convert_p_to_s1(void *p)
{
    int q = ((struct s2*)p)->x[0]+1;
    ((struct s1*)p)->x[0] = q-1;
}

int test(struct s1 *p1, struct s2 *p2)
{
    p1->x[0] = 1;
    p2->x[0] = 2;
    convert_p_to_s1(p1);
    return p1->x[0];
}
```

Neither clang nor gcc will allow for the possibility that `test` might write member `x[0]` of a `struct s1` to a location, then write that same location using member `x[0]` of a `struct s2`, then read using `x[0]` of a `struct s2`, write using `x[0]` of a `struct s1`, and then read using `x[0]` of `struct s1`, with all reads and writes being performed by dereferencing pointers type `char*`, and with every read of an lvalue derived from a structure pointer preceded by a write of that storage by an lvalue derived in the same way from a pointer of the same type.

Prior to C99, it was pretty much universally recognized that quality implementations should refrain from applying the type-access rules in ways that would be detrimental to their customers, without regard for whether the Standard would require such restraint.  Because some implementations were used for purposes which required the ability to access objects in weird ways but wouldn't require fancy optimizations, while others were used for purposes that didn't need to access storage in tricky fashion but required more optimizations, the question of exactly when implementations should recognize that an access to one object might affect another was left as a Quality of Implementation issue.

Some authors of C99, however, likely objected to the fact that the rules didn't actually require that implementations support constructs that all implementations should support, and in fact nearly all implementations were already supporting.  To address what they saw as a defect, they added some additional rules which would mandate support for some constructs they thought all implementations should support, and which would deliberately not mandate support for some constructs for which universal support should not have been required.  They do not appear, however, to have made any significant effort to consider corner cases and whether the rules would handle them sensibly.

The only way the Standard can ever say anything useful about pointer aliasing will be if the authors are willing to acknowledge that some tasks require stronger guarantees than others, and implementations intended for different kinds of tasks should be expected to uphold different guarantees appropriate to those tasks.  Otherwise, C should be treated as two families of dialects--one of which requires that any storage which is ever accessed using a particular type never be accessed using any other during its lifetime, and one of which recognizes that operations on the target of a pointer which is freshly visibly derived from a pointer of another type may affect the object identified by the original pointer.